# How to dynamically add custom layout with dynamically set id?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a `main.xml` layout and other layout `other.xml` containing several subElements (`TextView, ImageView`). What I want to do is add dynamically to `main.xml` as a scrollable list `other.xml` elements. Actually do achieve this I use loop like:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflaterInstance = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view;
    View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutToKeepOtherLayouts);


for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOtherXmlLayouts; i++) {
view = layoutInflaterInstance.inflate(R.layout.otherXml, null);

TextView firstValueOfOtherXml = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.first);
TextView secondValueOfOtherXml = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.second);
ImageView thirdValueOfOtherXml = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.third);

firstValueOfOtherXml = setContent();
secondValueOfOtherXml = setContent();
thirdValueOfOtherXml = setContent();

((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(view, i, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}
```

This is how I add dynamically content to existing main.xml. Now I want to add some activity to firstValueOfOtherXml/secondValueOfOtherXml/thirdValueOfOtherXml and I tried with setting `onClick` event in `other.xml` in TextView/ImageView as follows (in upper for loop):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.otherXmlID);
                View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.otherXml);
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                    }
};
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

Unfortunatelly it works only for first `other.xml` layout added to `main.xml`. I think the problem is in ID's of added `other.xml` that I do not change it dynamically (maybe according to `i` in for loop). I would appreciate in any sollutions of adding dynamically layout elements with dinamically changed ID's of their subElements to make their identification possible.

Hope it is clear enough. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the android project's pattern :
The activity is the context in which every thing happens. Every Activity has it's view which can be set using setContentView, so when you use setContentView, you are actually setting the view of the current activity.

The first thing you have to do is launching an Activity (which is the global context) and then you do whatever work you have to do within the Activity

So you should first launch your new activity like you did :

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
     }
```

and in the onCreate method of your OtherActivity class, you shoud setContentView any layout xml file that you want to apply to your new current activity.

Xml files are only used to describe views.( Actually you can use Java to do it )

Comment: What you say is quite obvious. I dont ask how to change to other activity cause its not a problem. Maybe i misleadingly used word activity against event. With main activity class I have combined main.xml which consist of other views. As if main were list of contacts(xx) and their view elements were each contact(image+description). As a response to onclick action on one of list contacts I want to go to other view (yes, switch activity and connected with it layout). The problem is how could I know which element(xx) were clicked. I thought that setting unique ID for every(xx) would solve this.

Comment: but in the code you presented, in the onClick method you are using setContentView just before switching activity, why do you set the activity's layout when you are leaving it ?
As for the ID, you ken get it from the View argument of the onClick method, view.getID() and pass it to the other activity via intent.putExtra  and handle it in the OtherActivity

Comment: Explanation and sollution for problem in my answer. Thanks for tip;)

Answer (score 0):

YAT's answer accepted due to my missunderstanding with activities "pattern". The sollution for my problem (switch to other activity filling layout.xml with proper data) was to use onClick="switchToWeekWeather" on RelativeLayout with this in WeatherActivity.java class:

public void switchToWeekWeather(View view) {

```
    TextView cityNameTextView = (TextView) ((RelativeLayout) view).getChildAt(1);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CityWeatherActivity.class);
    String cityName = cityNameTextView.getText().toString();
    myIntent.putExtra("name", cityName);
    startActivity(myIntent);

}
```

And in CityWeatherActivity.java:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = "";
        if (extras != null) {
            value = extras.getString("name");
        }

        LinearLayout cityView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().from(this).inflate(R.layout.cityview, null);
        TextView cityTextView = (TextView) cityView.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        cityTextView.setText(value);
        setContentView(cityView);

    }

    public void backToMain(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WeatherActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

    }
```